# Routing to default resource but use the same resource with ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the default resource in my routes.rb to add clients to my applications via `resources :clients`. But I'd like to be able to access that `new` page of clients via a group_id aswell.

So I want access like `/clients/new/` and as `clients/new/1/` or something.

I've tried adding my group to my path like `new_client_path(group)` but it gives me a .3 and showing the params shows that the 3 is called 'format'.

So, Long story short: How can I get a group_id to my `clients/new/` page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
resources :groups
  resources :clients
end
```

Now to get new client form with group id set you just need:

```
new_group_client_path(group)
```

assuming, of course, that `group` variable holds an `Group` instance.

If you don't want to use nested resources, you can set `group_id` this way

```
new_client_path(group_id: group)
```

Comment: Remember that you can view all the routes in your application, and the name of their helpers, by running `rake routes`.